# WSDL to Array php

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

A web service that I want to use to put data into an array in the project
I did not see a good answer.

This web service returns the info of a blog post, how data is in loop?

By writing these codes, I got the arrays in a string:

```
<?php
$client = new 
SoapClient('http://service.test.com/test_information.asmx?wsdl');

$param = array('username' => 'admin','password' => 'admin','feature' => 
'SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS');

$result  = $client->GetInfoWeblog($param);

$outterArray  = ((array)$result);

$innerArray  = ((array)$outterArray['GetInfoWeblogResult']);

$dataArray  = ((array)$innerArray['listObject']);

$array = json_decode(json_encode($dataArray), True);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
```

**output**

```
array(1) {
["OPMWebBlog"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(9) {
  ["WebVcCode"]=>
  int(1)
  ["WebTitle"]=>
  string(9) "Webtitle1"
  ["WebBody"]=>
  string(8) "WebBody1"
  ["WebUrl"]=>
  string(7) "Weburl1"
  ["WebDesc"]=>
  string(8) "WebDesc1"
  ["WebDatetimeInsert"]=>
  string(19) "2007-05-08T12:35:00"
  ["WebDatetimeUpdate"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-06T14:56:00"
  ["WebTag"]=>
  string(8) "Web Tag1"
  ["WebPublishActive"]=>
  bool(true)
}
[1]=>
array(9) {
  ["WebVcCode"]=>
  int(2)
  ["WebTitle"]=>
  string(9) "Webtitle2"
  ["WebBody"]=>
  string(8) "WebBody2"
  ["WebUrl"]=>
  string(7) "Weburl2"
  ["WebDesc"]=>
  string(8) "WebDesc2"
  ["WebDatetimeInsert"]=>
  string(19) "2018-11-06T14:56:00"
  ["WebDatetimeUpdate"]=>
  string(23) "2007-05-08T12:35:29.123"
  ["WebTag"]=>
  string(8) "Web Tag2"
  ["WebPublishActive"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

I want to get these objects in a loop

WebTitle

WebBody

WebUrl

WebDesc

WebDatetimeInsert

WebTag

WebPublishActive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you loop through `$array['OPMWebBlog']` you will get what you want :

```
foreach ($array['OPMWebBlog'] as $item) {
    echo $item['WebTitle'];
    echo $item['WebBody'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: merci @amirhosseindz. ok.